# Running noScribe with WINE/Crossover/Gameporting Toolkit

Tags: homebrew, wine

I am trying to run [noScribe](https://github.com/kaixxx/noScribe) (for AI supported transcription of audio files) with the new Game porting toolkit (I know, it's not a game, but to my understanding it should still run, since it's based on Crossover). I can install the software so the WINE env basically works. However, if I try to start the complete app, it crashes with this error log:

```
Unhandled exception: divide by zero in 64-bit code (0x000000044e1264).
...
Backtrace:
=>0 0x000000044e1264 in extension.cp39-win_amd64.pyd (+0x1264) (0x00000000306a30)
...
50 0x0000007b62a889 BaseThreadInitThunk+0x9(unknown=<internal error>, entry=<internal error>, arg=<internal error>) [Z:\private\tmp\game-porting-toolkit-20230610-60711-10941im\wine\dlls\kernel32\thread.c:61] in kernel32 (0000000000000000)
  51 0x0000017005b3b8 __wine_pop_frame(unknown=<internal error>, entry=<internal error>, arg=<internal error>) [Z:\private\tmp\game-porting-toolkit-20230610-60711-10941im\wine\include\wine\exception.h:275] in ntdll (0000000000000000)
  52 0x0000017005b3b8 RtlUserThreadStart+0x88(entry=[<register RSP not accessible in this frame>, arg=[<register RSP not accessible in this frame>) [Z:\private\tmp\game-porting-toolkit-20230610-60711-10941im\wine\dlls\ntdll\thread.c:240] in ntdll (0000000000000000)
...
```

The complete error log has 201 lines, but I am willing to share, if someone has an idea, what's wrong.

Comment: Questions about software development are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This is not a software dev question

Comment: The Game porting toolkit is new with macOS 14, right?

Comment: It's a beta that was written for Sonoma, but it also works with Ventura. People are playing Diablo 4 with it on a Ventura mac. So, it should be able to run a "simple" Windows application since it's based on WINE/Crossover. Seems like there is an issue with the `extension.cp39-win_amd64.pyd`.